# Kubernetes ExternalName type Service for Mongodb Atlas mongodb+srv:// url scheme

Tags: kubernetes, mongodb-atlas

I created externalservice in kubernetes for easier access to mongodb-atlas for some of my services hosted in kubernetes cluster.

The url it self is

```
mongodb+srv://accounting.xxxxx.mongodb.net
```

Here is my yaml file

```yaml
# mongodb accounting
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mongodb-accounting
  namespace: kasirmudah
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: accounting.xxxxx.mongodb.net
```

when i tried to connect with mongosh i got this

```
root@nginx-from-dev-6fb76d7868-fnqmv:/# mongosh "mongodb+srv://mongodb-accounting.kasirmudah.svc.cluster.local"
Current Mongosh Log ID: 6481c0914bfb085aeb92a7d4
Connecting to:      mongodb+srv://mongodb-accounting.kasirmudah.svc.cluster.local/?appName=mongosh+1.9.1
Error: querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.mongodb-accounting.kasirmudah.svc.cluster.local
```

it runs normally when i use the original url itself.

```
Connecting to:      mongodb+srv://<credentials>@accounting.xxxxx.mongodb.net/appName=mongosh+1.9.1
Using MongoDB:      6.0.6
Using Mongosh:      1.9.1

For mongosh info see: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/

Atlas atlas-11p0gl-shard-0 [primary] test>
```

it also runs normally when i put another webpage in the externalName and test it with cURL. is it possible to do this since as far i know, mongodb+srv::// scheme is like a "shortlink" from multiple mongodb replicas url.